# How to get GIT log for moved directories

Tags: git, tortoisegit

After re-arranging a bunch of directories using "git mv", I can get the full history of individual files by using "git log --follow", but when using that on a directory, it doesn't show the full history, just what happened *after* the move.

Since the directories moved contain thousands of files with many changes, it's not really practical to reconstruct the history by going through the directories file by file.

What am I missing here?

Incidently, haven't found a way to do this with TortoiseGit either...

Answer (score 0):

Albeit not an ideal method, if you "git mv" the directory back to it's original location, the full history appears again.

Still hoping that someone knows of a method that will show the full history of all files in a directory without having to resort to what I just described.